# How do you use a variable in a Puppet Manifest?

Tags: puppet, centos7, wsus, environment-variables, puppetmaster

I am using the WSUS Module with Puppet Master on Centos 7.2.  My Puppet Agent servers are running Windows Server 2012.

I want to use a manifest with a variable.  However, when the Puppet Agent server has the puppet agent run, it displays "error 400, syntax error."  I have tried re-writing the manifest and every variation I could think of.  I keep getting some error.

Here is one example of a manifest:

```
class excellent {
    class { 'wsus_client':
       $cool = 'Saturday'
    server_url => 'http://acme.com',
    auto_update_option  => 'Scheduled'
    scheduled_install_day => $cool,
    scheduled_install_hour => 1,
}
}
```

I've tried assigning the variable in braces {}.  I tried to use $LOAD_PATH, --custom-dir and FACTERLIB.  But I could not figure out how to use any of these three.

I want to change the variable in one place and use it within the scope of its parent class.  What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried it this way?

```
class excellent {
  $cool = 'Saturday'

  class { 'wsus_client':
    server_url => 'http://acme.com',
    auto_update_option  => 'Scheduled'
    scheduled_install_day => $cool,
    scheduled_install_hour => 1,
  }
}
```

Or, this way

```
class excellent (
  $cool = 'Saturday'
){
  class { 'wsus_client':
    server_url => 'http://acme.com',
    auto_update_option  => 'Scheduled'
    scheduled_install_day => $cool,
    scheduled_install_hour => 1,
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: @StefanLasiewski  yes, the second one makes `$cool` be a parameter for the class `excellent`.  Meaning you could set it in heira, or in your class declaration for `excellent`.

Answer (score 1):

You currently seem to be attempting to assign a value to a variable within the [class declaration](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#using-resource-like-declarations).  Your variable assignment needs to be separate.

```
$cool = 'Saturday'
```

Your class declaration should look like this.

```
class {'namevar':
  a => 'a',
  b => 'b',
  c => 'c'
}
```